# Alternative of Eraser Tool(Fabric js) for a open source Eraser tool

Tags: javascript, php, paint, fabricjs

I want to create an **online drawing tool using fabric js** deployed in a PHP web page.Most of the customized tools of fabric,js,  i created successfully.

But i cannot create Eraser tool like in **MS Paint eraser**..

I found this alternative method for eraser.This will do mask whilte color in the object

```
function eraser() {
   mode = 'pencil';
   canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
   canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = strokeWidth;
   canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'white';
}
```

But, I want to create an eraser similar to MS Paint.
I checked in SO, [In Fabric js there is no built in eraser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311038/fabric-js-eraser-issue-canvas)

Plz any one help me.

Is it possible to make eraser in fabric js?.

if not possible, Can you suggest any easy **alternative of fabric js**,  like any **open source/free web drawing tool** which will **support the function of eraser**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately fabric.js does not support this functionality. I think the best way to do this is drawing with the background color, like this example: http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/

However I found this great example: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/WUXDb/1/

```
var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
var radius = 10; // or whatever
var fillColor = '#ff0000';
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ptCoder,  I m using this metthod only now.If cannt do in fabric js , plz suggest me any other alternate drawing tool which support eraser.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25916334/2247124. You may accept the answer if that helped ;)

Comment: Yes thanks prCoder.Your answer helped me. But paint like eraser wont support in fabric js.

Answer (score 2):

This possibility exists, however you should reverse the action for when you just draw:

```
//eraser
    canvas.on('path:created', function (opt) {
        opt.path.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        opt.path.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
        opt.path.stroke = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
        //opt.path.fill = 'black';
        canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });

 //draw
 canvas.on('path:created', function (opt) {
        opt.path.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
        opt.path.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
        opt.path.stroke = 'black';
        //opt.path.fill = 'black';
        canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });
```

Comment: when this eraser commented  method will call?